# Had a hard time factoring out $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ from $\frac{1}{\lambda} (2n) - \frac{1}{\lambda^{3}}\sum_{i}^{n} Y_{i}$

Tags: factoring

I just had an exam that I am nervous about, and at some point I had to factorize

$$
\frac{1}{\lambda}
$$

or
$$
\lambda$$ out of the following expression that I wrote up from memory(don't have access to what I handed in):

$$
\frac{1}{\lambda} (2n) - \frac{1}{\lambda^{3}}\sum_{i}^{n} (Y_{i}) = -n\log{(2)} - 2n
$$

My plan was to factorize $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ out and then I could divide both sides with the term inside of the parenthesis. Is that even possible? I might've taken a wrong turn earlier in the assignment, I think. Would have to had been done by hand in the exam.

EDIT: The goal is to isolate lambda from everything else.

Comment: Either you made a mistake somewhere earlier, or the teacher made a mistake in preparing the exam (it happens), or the teacher expected you to know how to solve a [depressed cubic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Depressed_cubic) by hand. Depending on the course, the latter is possible, but it is far more likely that there was a mistake, and it is also much more likely the mistake was yours.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yeah I had to differentiate before this step and I used the chain rule on an expression where the inner function was a fraction and the outer an exponent. The inside function I used the quotient rule to differentiate and I think I probably should have used the multiplication rule instead to get something nicer at this step. Sucks :)